# django orm how to use values and still work with modeltranslation

Tags: django, django-orm, django-modeltranslation

I am using django v1.10.2

I am trying to create dynamic reports whereby I store fields and conditions and the main orm model information into database.

My code for the generation of the dynamic report is

```
class_object = class_for_name("app.models", main_model_name)
results = class_object.objects\
        .filter(**conditions_dict)\
        .values(*display_columns)\
        .order_by(*sort_columns)\
        [:50]
```

So `main_model_name` can be anything.

This works great except that the related models are actually registered with `django-modeltranslation` and their names do not appear with the right translation field.

So for one of the reports `main_model` is `ProductVariant`. `ProductVariant` hasMany `Pattern`.

My display columns are :`serial_number`, `created_at`, `pattern__name`

The first two columns are fields that belong to `ProductVariant` model.
The last one is from `Pattern`

Pattern model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class Pattern(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Pattern Name'), max_length=400)
    serial_number = models.CharField(_('Pattern Number'), max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + ' (' + str(self.serial_number) + ')'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Pattern')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Patterns')
```

The queryset calling `values()` does not return me the expected language `zh_hans` for the field `pattern__name`.

I read the documentation about `multilingual managers` at http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#multilingual-manager but I still do not know how to make this work.

Bear in mind that the `main_model` can be anything depending on what I store in the database.

Comment: It is probably better to write a patch for [django-modeltranslation](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) package than to write a workaround solution, because the package seems not enough documented and there are related issues [Fallback on foreignkey don’t return translation when we use values method](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/issues/392) or [Values and relationship spanning not translating](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/issues/409).

Comment: When you call values() Django waits to get string static field-name, in your case its a pattern__name_zh or something. on display_columns you should pass fieldname+ '_lang', when you try to get value for default field name ORM gives you default lang field - en, as I know.